# Allocate memory to user application from kernel

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel

I want to allocate small pages (two or three) to current application process from the kernel.

Is there any way to do it ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623008/allocating-memory-for-user-space-from-kernel-thread)? This is the first question in the "Related" list. What is specific of your question against it?

Comment: Yes I have checked that one, and know it violates the custom, but I want to do it for research purpose thanks